# Resize an image into popup

Tags: javascript, popup, image-resizing

I have a popup with an image in it. I would like to know if it's possible to set size for my image. I've made this script for my popup:

```
function open_win(title, description, src, alt)
{
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.alt = alt;

    myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=300, height=300, left=700, top=400')
    myWindow.document.write("<div class='description'> <img src=" + src + " alt=" + alt + " >")
    myWindow.document.write("<h4>" + title + "</h4>")
    myWindow.document.write("<p>" + description + "</p></div>")

    document.body.appendChild(img)

    myWindow.focus()
}
```

I would like my picture to be  1185x785. I've searched how to do that, but I've got just answers with resizing the window and I don't need that. I just want to resize my image.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
img.style.width='1185px';
img.style.height='785px';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!
  I just have to change this line:

```
    myWindow.document.write("<div class='description'> <img src=" + src + " alt=" + alt + " >")
```

with this one

```
    myWindow.document.write("<div class='description'> <img src=" + src + " alt=" + alt + " width=1185 height=785 >")
```